# How to cope with program privileges for a logger

Tags: c#, wpf, process, privileges

I have a logger program that has to take log all activities of a program.
So the trick is that the logger has to have the same privileges of the main program.

So problem 1 shall be to discover the privileges of a running process.

Then I am able to set privileges of a program through App.manifest but NOT at runtime.

So problem 2 shall be to change privileges of a program at runtime. Is that possible?!?!?

Thanks

Comment: What kinds of things is your logger logging? Also why the requirement that the logger must have the exact same privileges as the running program?

Comment: I am logging a  program of another company. They said -and I have verificated it- that they have to have exactly the same privilges

Comment: I did not ask what program was your program logging, I wanted to know "what types of information is your logger recording" Also, if you can't get it to work, how did you verifiy that you needed it?

Comment: I am logging start / stop / errors. I can get it to work but only if LOGGING=PROGRAM=HIGHEST or LOGGING=PROGRAM=normal. So MANUALLY launched both with the same privileges. And by doing so everything works fine. Otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are aware of what the privileges of that program are, you could make a launcher that launches two different programs built with different App.manifest privileges.

Comment: That might be a solution. Not very smart though

Answer (score 0):

You will need to demand full privileges because you will be debugging another process.

The debug API itself demands unmanaged code which is equivalent to full.

Comment: No that's not working please see the comment to Scott above

Comment: They're wrong, and if they were right, and you had really verified it, you wouldn't be asking this question as you would already have the answer in hand.